# Fetching all cucumber scenarios that have a particular tag

Tags: cucumber, scenarios, feature-file

How can I fetch a list of all the scenarios that have a particular tag. For example
get all scenarios that have @checkout tag.

Comment: Do u want to execute all the scenarios tagged with @checkout or u want to list down their name, please elaborate.

Comment: I want to list down their names. I have a option of going through full log & search but that's very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

***Lets assume you have 15-20 Scenarios/Scenarios Outline tagged with @checkout.***

```
  @checkout
  Scenario Outline: Validation of UseCase Guest User Order Placement flow from Search
    Given User is on Brand Home Page <Site>
    And User searches for a styleId and makes product selection on the basis of given color and size
      | Style_ID  | Product_Size | Product_Color |
      | TestData1 | TestData1    | TestData1     |
      | TestData2 | TestData2    | TestData2     |
    Then Clicking on Cart icon shall take user to Shopping Bag
```

*Please follow this way to fetch name of scenarios.*

*File name Hook.java*

```
@Before
    public void setUpScenario(Scenario scenario){
        String scenarioName = scenario.getName();
        //Either you can write down name of the scenario under a file system like excel or implement in the way you want
        }
```

***Please lets know if you find it meaningful and it solved your problem.***

Answer (score 0):

Dry run to the rescue.

Dry run gives you a way to quickly scan your features without actually running them.

Try the following CucumberOptions annotations (this is Java/Junit version, but the idea applies everywhere)

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, glue = {
        "some.stepdef" }, features = { "src/cucumberTest/featureFiles" }, tags = { "@now" }
        ,dryRun = true, strict=true)
public class CucumberNowTestDryRunner {
}
```

The cucumber report will look like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestions, Dry run worked out fine. I'd also like to try solution provided by 'The Society'